# Как правильно пишется: "контроль за загрязнением поверхности" или "контроль загрязнения поверхности"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно пишется: "контроль за загрязнением поверхности" или "контроль загрязнения поверхности"?

Answer (score 2):

Из "Словаря трудностей русского языка"<sup>1</sup>:

> Контро́ль, -я. Управление: *за чем*, *над чем*, *чего*.
>
> 1. *за чем* и *над чем* (при отглагольных сущ.);
> 2. *над чем* (при отвлеченных сущ. не глагольного происхождения и при сущ. одушевленных);
> 3. *чего* (в официальной и профессионально-технической речи).

В вашем случае выбор зависит от контекста: либо 1, либо 3.

---

1. Розенталь Д. Э., Теленкова М. А. Словарь трудностей русского языка. — 3-е изд. — М.: Айрис-пресс, 2003.